# Images are not loading from cloud firestore?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am making a simple application using firebase in which the user can add an image in firebase but the problem is images are not loading properly. Also, I used many image loading libraries like Picasso, Glide, Coil but the problem is not solved.

AllPhotos.kt

```
class AllPhotos : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var appBar: MaterialToolbar
    lateinit var appBarLayout: AppBarLayout
    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var addPostBtn: FloatingActionButton
    lateinit var actionBarDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
    lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var navView: NavigationView
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
    lateinit var collectionReference: CollectionReference
    lateinit var postsList: ArrayList<Posts>
    lateinit var photoAdapter: PhotoAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_photos)

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        appBar = findViewById(R.id.topAppBar)
        appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout)
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
        addPostBtn = findViewById(R.id.openAddPostScreen)
        navView = findViewById(R.id.navView)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        collectionReference = firestore.collection(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.email.toString())
        postsList = arrayListOf()

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)


        setUpDrawerLayout()

        addPostBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, AddPost::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        displayPosts()

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.profile -> {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
                    val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.signOut -> {

                    firebaseAuth.signOut()
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "User signed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            true
        }
        navView.menu.getItem(0).isChecked = true
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private fun displayPosts() {
        
        collectionReference.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->

            when (error != null) {
                true -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                false -> {
                    for (listDocument in value!!.documentChanges) {
                        if (listDocument.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            postsList.add(listDocument.document.toObject(Posts::class.java))
                            Log.d(
                                "ALL_POSTS",
                                listDocument.document.toObject(Posts::class.java).toString()
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    photoAdapter = PhotoAdapter(this, postsList)
                    recyclerView.adapter = photoAdapter
                    photoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setUpDrawerLayout() {
        setSupportActionBar(appBar)
        actionBarDrawerToggle =
            ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Posts.kt

```
data class Posts(
    var description: String = "",
    var imageUri: String = "",
    var postDate: String = ""
)
```

PhotoAdapter.kt

```
class PhotoAdapter(val context: Context, val postsList: ArrayList<Posts>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoAdapter.PhotoViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PhotoViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false)
        return PhotoViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PhotoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = postsList[position]
        holder.descText.text = currentItem.description

        Glide.with(context).load(currentItem.imageUri).into(holder.postImageView)
        holder.dateText.text = currentItem.postDate
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return postsList.size
    }

    class PhotoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val postImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImages)
        val dateText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDate)
        val descText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDesc)
    }
}
```

Sample image of cloud firestore structure

[image: Sample image of cloud firestore structure]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Share the stacktrace . There might be error you are missing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `imageUri` value in the screenshot starts with `content://`, which means that is points to a specific file on a specific device. If you share that URL with another user, the file won't exist on their device - so it has nothing to show.

What you'll want to do is [upload the file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) from the source device to a cloud storage location, [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) for that uploaded file, and then store **that** download URL in the database.

Comment: Now it is fixed and works very well.